# I have a table of attendances that has staff_id, absent_year, absent_month, absent_day as primarykey in laravel, While updating I face to bellow error

Tags: laravel-7

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `attendances` where (`0` = staff_id and `1` = absent_year and `2` = absent_month and `3` = absent_day) limit 1)

[My-Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5XhI.png)
[My-Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XxPA.png)

Comment: which column is you primary key?

Comment: Akbar, please don't use code image. Its a violation of the SO guideline. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Put just the primary key of your table in the where constraint

```
$update= DB::table('attendances')
    where('staff_id', $attendance['staff_id'])
    ->update([
    'absent_year'=> $attendance['absent_year'],
    'absent_month'=> $attendance['absent_month'],
    'absent_day'=> $attendance['absent_day'],
    'hours'=> $attendance['hours'],
    ]);
```

Comment: My table has composite primary key, staff_id, absent_year, absent month and absent_day

Comment: I tried the above code that you write but it returned me the same error

Comment: Finally find it, I tried the bellow code.

Comment: $update= DB::table('attendances')
          ->where('staff_id', $attendance['staff_id'])
          ->where('absent_year', $attendance['absent_year'])
          ->where('absent_month', $attendance['absent_month'])
          ->where('absent_day', $attendance['absent_day'])
          ->update([
          'absent_year'=> $request['absent_year'],
          'absent_month'=> $request['absent_month'],
          'absent_day'=> $request['absent_day'],
          'hours'=> $request['hours'],
        ]);